# Create a plugin based controller in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

How to create a plugin based controller in Umbraco? I have followed the guide on https://github.com/Shandem/Umbraco4Docs/blob/4.8.0/Documentation/Reference/Mvc/surface-controllers.md.

But when browsing to ~/umbraco/areaname/controllername I get a 404. The only way not getting this is removing the plugin attribute. But I want to use the plugin architecture. So what else needs to be done besides the instruction mentioned in the guide.

The documentation is really awful if you want to get started with Umbraco and MVC.

By the way I am using Umbraco 6.

Comment: if you could solve the problem, please visit 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/33509696/1817640

Answer (score 2):

you're area needs to be under the App_Plugins folder.

Sorry misunderstood the question, but it seems you figured it out as you explain in the post linked bellow.

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/39704-Create-a-plugin-based-controller-in-Umbraco

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry for cross posting by the way. The answer was that the Surface prefix had to be added to the controller.